Blazor HttpClient get data from Http POST
I'm trying to get my Blazor Web-App to display data from a Http POST sent through CURL, But I'm having trouble with anti-forgery validation.
My Blazor page source:
@page "/Data"
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<PageTitle>Data</PageTitle>

<h1>POST:</h1>

<p>@(rqData != null?rqData:"NoData!") </p>

@code {
    private string? rqData;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetData();
    }

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            // Send POST request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7084/data", null);

            // Check if request was successful
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read response content
            rqData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            // Handle any errors
            rqData = "Error: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
}

And I'm testing this with a sample CURL request:
curl -X POST https://localhost:7084/data -d "key=value"

But this method doesn't really comply with Blazor's default Anti-forgery token system in any way, and thus, fails. What would be the proper way to handle these requests with token validation on both, the Blazor web-app side of things and when testing it's functionality with CURL. Sorry if this question is noob-ish, I'm very new to this level of interconnectivity within Blazor Apps.

What's the actual error? How is this related to antiforgery tokens? Does the remote API expect such a token? Why not create it then and pass it as a header in the request body? Are you sure the problem isn't CORS? Browsers don't allow any script to connect to a URL outside the page's origin (the O in CORS), unless the source server specified it's OK. HttpClient already targets the original server which probably means https://localhost:7084/data targets a different origin and thus fails CORS

@PanagiotisKanavos On the blazor app I get a 400-bad Request error, regardless whether I send anything to the app. The CURL command specified above returns this: A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation for this endpoint. localhost:7084 is where my app is hosted locally. Like I said, I'm completely new to these aspects of web-development and I couldn't find more specific resources on this.

You don't need to pass an explicit address in that case. HttpClient's base address already points to the server. As for the token, the easiest way is to check the docs. There's a code example as well.

As for these aspects of web-development they haven't changed since the 2000s. To prevent malicious form posts, all platforms add a token to a form, usually as a hidden field, that's included in form posts. Form posts that don't include the token get rejected. This is the most basic way of protecting against fake POSTs.

@PanagiotisKanavos Is my approach a valid method for receiving data from Http POSTs and displaying said data on the Blazor page?

POST is used to send, not receive data. That's what GET is for. The code is wrong for multiple reasons, including the hard-code URL that will fail after deployment, using POST instead of GET to receive data and not sending a body with POST. If you want to retrieve data, var data=await client.GetAsStringAsync(relative_url); is enough. If the API returns JSON of a certain type, the way the WeatherForecast API does in the project template, var forecast=await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast>("api/Forecast") is more than enough. The project template already contains such code

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry for all the confusion. The API I'm supposed to integrate to this app works by only sending Http POST:s to a designated url. It doesn't accept or react to any http requests itself, the transfer of data is completely one-sided. I've directed the traffic to a webhook.site instance, and the incoming data seems to noly be a Http POST with a JSON payload. I'm only using CURL for testing this since I'd have to either deploy my app or somehow route the POST to my locally hosted instance of my web app.

The API code itself asks for the token. You need to create an HttpRequestMessage with the correct header even if the body is empty. The code example from the docs doesn't use a body either
